# Is Bluetooth a bottleneck for audio quality when using a headset?

Tags: bluetooth, digital-audio

**Context - My hearing impaired friend cant hear me well when I use a Bluetooth headset**

A close friend and I enjoy talking on the phone while commuting. Unfortunately his hearing has gotten worse (probably to be considered a real hearing impairment) and it is getting difficult for us to talk.

I have tried a few different Bluetooth headsets and I have tried the built-in stereo in my car, but it seems that with all of them, my voice does not go through as well as I could wish for.

My phone (OnePlus Nord) does a good job though. Whether I set it on speaker mode or not the microphone picks up my voice very well and he can hear everything I say. Also if I keep the phone some distance from my face or in front of my chest (where the microphone from the headsets typically rest) and also in the car with all the background noise.

One of the headsets was a reasonably high end ISOtunes, but it picks up audio terribly compared to my phone.

**Is Bluetooth a bottleneck?**

I totally understand that there could be many explanations for the problems, but in this thread I mainly want to ask one specific question.

Could the fact that I'm using Bluetooth (as opposed to an old fashioned cable) be part of the explanation?

Maybe the technology is not there yet. I understand that there is some kind of quality loss in digitization and compression, but I'm not talking about studio recording here. I am talking about the ability to make a voice clear and intelligible; as good as a regular phone call.

And if the technology in fact is there, then maybe it takes a lot of energy for a headset to both encode/compress and transmit the audio, so most headsets on the market went for a compromise in quality in order to put longer battery life on the packaging as a selling point?

**Why am I asking?**

Curiosity is one thing.

I have started looking for a better headset. If Bluetooth technology is well ahead and should not be a concern, then I will look for a Bluetooth headset. If Bluetooth is likely to be the bottleneck I might look for a wired headset instead.

Comment: probably not. Bluetooth audio has come a very long way and is generally pretty good now. It's more likely about mic placement and the (very sophisticated) way that most handsets are tailored for speech intelligibility, which a headset may not be (especially if the mics do the dual job of picking up voice AND doing active noise cancellation).

Comment: I wonder if Bluetooth is doing some form of [companding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companding) or frequency bandwidth limiting/alteration which coincides with the friend's particular hearing loss?